# Not able to select options in select Box in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi I am using Kendo UI in my project.

I have created the select box template like this.

```
GENERIC_COMPONENT_COMBO  :
 kendo.template("<select id='#= id #' class='#= id #' multiple></select>"),
```

and i am appending the template like this.

```
  $("#showHideColumns").append('<tr><td class="table-drawer-left-col   
 rp5">'+this.GENERIC_COMPONENT_COMBO({id:"showHideSelect"})+'
 </td></tr></table>');
```

and on fly i am putting options as follows:

```
var data = $si.viewer.drawerData.attributes.attribute;

        $.each(data , function(key, value ) {
drawer.find("#showHideSelect").append('<option>'+value.name+'</option>');
        });
```

Data is coming properly, but i am not able to select options of select box in chrome.

it is working on mozilla but On chrome it is acting as disabled.

I have not set any thing as disabled but still i am not able to select any options.

what should i have to do so that this will work in chrome also.

Comment: Can you post the rendered html?

Comment: <select id="showHideSelect" class="showHideSelect" multiple=""><option>a</option><option>b</option><option>c</option><option>d</option><option>d</option><option>d</option><option>e</option><option>f</option><option>g</option><option>h</option></select>

Answer (score 0):

Update kendo.web.min.js and kendo.common.min.css to latest file. i hope this will help..